# How do I check a new Numbers file into git using Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bundle, apple-numbers

Apple's "Numbers" spreadsheet app just changed file formats, where the new one is bundle-based, essentially a single-icon representation as far as a user is concerned, but a folder of stuff under the hood. I have a spreadsheet where I keep track of App Store data and other things related to my app, and I love keeping it under source control closely tied to my source code and other project data.

What's the best way to add/commit the new file (actually a folder) into git? Ideally, it would be treated just like the old single-file-format file was treated. If I add it like I would normally do, it adds the folder with 50 files inside, and I'm worried that git won't keep up with the files that Numbers (transparently to the user) adds and removes inside that "bundle".

I found this previous post, but it wasn't helpful: [Best approaches to versioning Mac "bundle" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027/best-approaches-to-versioning-mac-bundle-files)

Basically, I don't want to "manage" anything related to what's inside the folder. Is there a way to do this right?